# React Native react navigation redux handle Android back button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am following the docs trying to handle the Android back button when using react navigation integrated with redux.

Currently pressing the back button exits the entire app wherever you press it. I have tried to handle back press following the guides by adding the handler on the Root component:

```
 const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
      blacklist: ['nav'],
    };

    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
      {
        SelectScreen,
        PageScreen,
        SettingsScreen,
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'SelectScreen',
      },
    );

    const navReducer = createNavigationReducer(AppNavigator);
    const appReducer = combineReducers({
      nav: navReducer,
      theme: themeReducer,
      page: pageReducer,
    });
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, appReducer);

    const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware('root', state => state.nav);

    const App = reduxifyNavigator(AppNavigator, 'root');
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      state: state.nav,
    });
    const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

    const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(middleware));
    const persistor = persistStore(store);

    class Root extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }

  onBackPress = () => {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    if (nav.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }

    dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
    return true;
  };
      render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
              <AppWithNavigationState />
            </PersistGate>
          </Provider>
        );
      }
    }

    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Root);
```

However, I am getting an error because the navigation props doesn't exist in the root component. I know this is probably an error due to my lack of understanding so I'd really appreciate some help on how to get this working!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by passing it to another component which has access to the `Provider store`.

### **AppNavigation.js**

```
const PrimaryNav = createStackNavigator(
      {
        SelectScreen,
        PageScreen,
        SettingsScreen,
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'SelectScreen',
      },
 );

export const appNavigatorMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
  'root',
  state => state.nav
); //... Import it to your configure store file, to apply the middleware

const AppNavigator = reduxifyNavigator(PrimaryNav, 'root');

export default AppNavigator
```

**ReduxNavigation.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { BackHandler, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation' //... Import from AppNavigation.js

class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  ...// Add your BackHandler Code here

  render () {
    return <AppNavigation state={this.props.nav}  dispatch={this.props.dispatch}/>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav })
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
```

### App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
         <RootContainer />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `appNavigatorMiddleware` should be imported where you'll create and initialize the `store` in the `applyMiddleware`, `RootContainer.js` is just another component, which you need to add to `App.js`

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't got enough rep I have to post this as an answer.

Have a read through this:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-android-back-button-handling.html

Have a look through the example but look at the listener in the constructor:

```
this._didFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload =>
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
);
```

Looks like you're on the right track, you just need to add the listener to the `props.navigation`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried that but I get an error, props.navigation is undefined. Still the same issue I initially had, there is no navigation prop in this component

Comment: What versions of React Native and Navigation are you using?